# Can't use Objective-C Pod Framework in Swift 2 project ("Use of undeclared type 'SMPageControl'")

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, swift2, xcode7

I have a Swift 2 project running on Xcode 7. I'm using CocoaPods (v 0.38.2 with `use_frameworks!`) and have already managed to get those frameworks working:

- CryptoSwift
- Pluralize_swift

Both Pods are written in Swift, so no problems so far. They work as charm.

Now I'm trying to use [SMPageControl](https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/SMPageControl) which is written in Objective-C. I've seen [it's possible to use Obj-C Pods with Swift 2](http://michal.codes/integrating-cocoapods-with-a-swift-project/), tried a lot of different combinations but I can't get it to work. `SMPageControl` class doesn't show on autocomplete suggestions, and obviously when I try to use it the compiler throws *`Use of undeclared type 'SMPageControl'`*.

What I have done so far:

1. Added `pod 'SMPageControl'` to my `Podfile`
2. Ran `pod install` (I can see the Pod source/framework on Xcode project tree)
3. Added `SMPageControl.framework` in Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries (as I've done with the other frameworks that work)
4. Created `PROJECT_NAME-Bridging-Header.h` and added it on the project's Build Settings (I can tell it's working because it threw errors until I got to import `SMPageControl` correctly)
5. Added `#import <SMPageControl/SMPageControl.h>` to the file above

Up to here the project compiles without errors, but I can't get to use `SMPageControl` in my Swift classes. Tried `import SMPageControl` in the Swift file, but no luck (it doesn't even autocomplete). I understood it's possible, but I didn't find any example codes.

Is it really possible? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you try `#import "SMPageControl.h"` or `#import <SMPageControl.h>`? In my project, I use this to link library from Pod, and it wok fine

Comment: @t4nhpt yes. Both cases you suggested fails to compile ("SMPageControl.h file not found"). The only way the project compiles is with the line mentioned on the question: `#import <SMPageControl/SMPageControl.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it to work, it turns out that I was actually *missing something*.

Along with all steps above, it's needed to `import` the framework at the top of the Swift file:

```
import SMPageControl
```

Since Xcode was not providing any autocomplete I thought it wouldn't be possible to do that. Once I added the `import` statement, the project compiled successfully and I was able to use `SMPageControl()` class.