# Bridging-header works, but imports are not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, bridging-header

I installed a library using CocoaPods, and it all seems to work. I added a bridging-header to my project, which I know works since I use several different libraries in this header. But I just installed and bridged [libPhoneNumber-iOS](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS) and it seems to work, except...it doesn't. I find the files, it imports them correctly in the header, but I can't use it in swift. It should be `NBPhoneNumberUtil`, but it doesn't exist.

I have imported them like this in my header:

```
#import "libPhoneNumber_iOS/NBPhoneNumberUtil.h"
#import "libPhoneNumber_iOS/NBPhoneNumber.h"
```

and if I type anything differently it will give me an error saying it can't the specified files, so this should be imported correctly. Also if I type `NBPhoneNumberUtil` in this header-file I can see the object so it works. But in my swift-project the modules doesn't exist. Again, I know my bridging-file works since I use other libraries in this file, and in swift. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Update #1:

So I tried adding import to my swift-file, and it "works".

```
import libPhoneNumber_iOS/NBPhoneNumberUtil
import libPhoneNumber_iOS/NBPhoneNumber
```

Except that Xcode complains that this is not a viable syntax, it wants to add a semi colon somewhere. But now I can create the objects I need, but I can't compile since Xcode wants me to fix the errors first. This is so weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add `#import "NBPhoneNumber.h"` in header of the swift file which you are using this class? With some libraries, we must `import` in both bridged-header file and swift file, but I don't known why.

Comment: And how would you do that? #import "NBPhoneNumber.h" is not swift-syntax so that won't work, and import NBPhoneNumber finds nothing :/

Comment: My mistake, I meant `import NBPhoneNumber`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well :/ No such module 'NBPhoneNumber'

Comment: There is no case I know of where a header would need to also be imported into a Swift file if it is already imported into a bridging header.

Comment: @DanielZhang, here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996631/cant-use-objective-c-pod-framework-in-swift-2-project-use-of-undeclared-type#comment53836307_32996631

Comment: @t4nhpt Thanks. If I ever see that happen I'll know what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to import them like this in your bridging header:

```
#import "NBPhoneNumberUtil.h"
#import "NBPhoneNumber.h"
```

The procedure that I used to test this is written below.

### Create a new Xcode project

I used the Single View Application template for Objective-C.

### Create Podfile and Install

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'
```

Install:

```
$ pod install
```

### Create a Swift file

At this point a bridging header file was created by Xcode.

I added the imports into the bridging header using:

```
#import "NBPhoneNumberUtil.h"
#import "NBPhoneNumber.h"
```

In the Swift file, I wrote:

```
class Test {
    func test() {
        let util = NBPhoneNumberUtil()
    }
}
```

**The project compiled without errors.**

Comment: Well, not if I installed them using CocoaPods? Since writing those import lines won't find the files. "NBPhoneNumberUtil.h" file not found.

Comment: @ClockWise Did you try it? I've tested this with Xcode 7 and libPhoneNumber-iOS (0.8.8) installed using CocoaPods 0.38.0.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it several times. I only find the files if I type #import "libPhoneNumber_iOS/NBPhoneNumberUtil.h"
#import "libPhoneNumber_iOS/NBPhoneNumber.h"

I use CocoaPods 0.39, libPhoneNumber-iOS (0.8.8)

Comment: I'll mark your post as the correct answer since it does install without issues :)

Edit: I tried it in a new project and it worked, but now I found the issue. I use_framework! in my podfile, and the paths gets messed up probably. In a new project when I added use_framework! it stopped working.

Comment: @ClockWise Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: Updated my precious comment, found the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved the issue now. The issue was that I use `use_frameworks!` in my pod file so the paths are different. In fact, when you use `use_frameworks!` you don't need a bridging header, and have to import the files directly in swift. The problem was that I didn't know how to import it, but now I do.

pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'test' do

pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'

end

target 'testTests' do

end
```

In the Xcode project you do not need a bridging header anymore, and simply import the library where you want to use it, like this:

```
import libPhoneNumber_iOS
```

Now it should be working. Hope this helps someone else.